# Aws sdk v3 javascript GetObjectCommand not returning expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

```
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand, PutObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

let client = new S3Client({
    region: 'xxxxx',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'xxxxx',
        secretAccessKey: 'xxxxx'
    }
});

const getObjectFromS3 = async (pdfFileName) => {
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: "xxxxxxx",
        Key: pdfFileName,
    });
    const response = await client.send(command);
    const content = await response.Body;

    console.log(content)
    return content; 
};
```

The thing is I am calling this function getObjectFromS3, and I am trying to get the binary of a pdf, I read everywhere that I could get it with the response.Body as seen above.
The problem is that when i console log the response, or the response body, they are the same! That giant object instead of the actual Body of the content!!

I receive an object of type IncomingMessage, when i console log both response, or response.Body

```
<ref *2> IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: [],
        awaitDrainWriters: null,
        [Symbol(kState)]: 1185840
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: responseOnEnd] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: <ref *1> TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: {
            allowHalfOpen: undefined,
            pipe: false,
            secureContext: [SecureContext],
            isServer: false,
            requestCert: true,
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
            session: undefined,
            ALPNProtocols: undefined,
            requestOCSP: undefined,
            enableTrace: undefined,
            pskCallback: undefined,
            highWaterMark: undefined,
            onread: undefined,
            signal: undefined
        },
        ...............
```

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Code Examples library includes an example scenario "[Get Started with Buckets and Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_Scenario_GettingStarted_section.html)" that includes a JavaScript version. This example includes downloading files, which calls transformToByteArray on the Body of the response:

```
export const downloadFilesFromBucket = async ({ bucketName }) => {
  const { Contents } = await s3Client.send(
    new ListObjectsCommand({ Bucket: bucketName }),
  );
  const path = await promptForText("Enter destination path for files:");

  for (let content of Contents) {
    const obj = await s3Client.send(
      new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: content.Key }),
    );
    writeFileSync(
      `${path}/${content.Key}`,
      await obj.Body.transformToByteArray(),
    );
  }
  console.log("Files downloaded successfully.\n");
};
```

You can also clone [the code examples repository](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascriptv3/example_code/s3#code-examples) and run these examples yourself.